# Two-variable limit question

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \dfrac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

How to solve this two-variable limit? Thanks :D

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE . What have you attempted till now ?

Comment: Did my hint help ?

Comment: Sure it helped a lot :)
I didn't learn this method before. It is really useful :)
And Brightsun confirmed my working. 
Thank you guys!!

Comment: The model answer of this question is like this:
$\dfrac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leq \dfrac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} < \sqrt{|xy|}$ Then it uses definition of limit to prove it equals 0.

But I don't think the first part is true as $y$ can be less than 1. Is this proof correct? Thanks :)

Comment: @SPMIHC you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to polar coordinates:
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^4\cos^2\varphi\sin^2\varphi}{(r^2\cos^2\varphi+r^4\sin^4\varphi)r} = \lim_{r\to 0} \left[r\frac{\cos^2\varphi\sin^2\varphi}{\cos^2\varphi+r^2\sin^4\varphi}\right]
$$
then we have to be careful and see what happens as $\varphi$ changes its values: let us consider $\varphi=\pi /2 + k\pi$, then our quantity vanishes identically and the limit is zero; however if $\phi \ne \pi /2 + k\pi $, for $r>0$ the fraction is always bounded since it can be expressed as:
$$
\frac{\sin^2\varphi}{1+r^2\sin^2\varphi \tan^2\varphi},
$$
therefore the limits is again zero.

Comment: Yes, but then how you conclude that the limit is indeed 0? If the fraction was always bounded, then okay. But it is not the case. So what do you do?

Comment: @Ant I tried to explain what I had in mind. Is it correct now?

Comment: yes I think so! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Put $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $ y = r\sin(\theta)$ and change the limit to $r \to 0$ .

Answer (score 0):

Let
\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\end{equation}
If $y=0$, $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}f(x,y)=0$. If $y\neq0$, say approach the $(0,0)$ do not along with x-axis, we have:
\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq\frac{x^2y^2}{2|x|y^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{|x|}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\
0\leq\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}f(x,y)\leq\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{|x|}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0
\end{equation}
In summary, $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}f(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)
Could you explain more why $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{|x|}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ equals 0? I am confused. Both the nominator and denominator tend to zero :O

Comment: If we approach $(0,0)$ not along with x-axis, we can set $x=0$ first and obtain the limitation is $0$. And then no matter what value of $y$, the limitation is zero.

Answer (score 0):

This might also be an approach:
$$0 \le \frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2 + y^4)\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \le \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \le \frac{y^2}{\sqrt{y^2}} \le |y|$$
So, since $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ then $|y| \to 0$ and passing to a limit we obtain that the initial expression goes to 0.